Calendar import statement giving error while executing test cases

Here are the files and code I have created in demo project.
Library I have used for calendar is React Native Calendars:
"react-native-calendars": "^1.1304.1"
App.tsx:
import React from 'react';
import { Calendar } from 'react-native-calendars';
import { SafeAreaView, StatusBar, StyleSheet, Text, useColorScheme} from 'react-native';
import { Colors } from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';


function App(): React.JSX.Element {
    const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
    const sum = (a: number, b: number): number => {
    return a + b;
};

const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
};

return (
  <SafeAreaView style={backgroundStyle}>
  <StatusBar
    barStyle={isDarkMode ? 'light-content' : 'dark-content'}
    backgroundColor={backgroundStyle.backgroundColor}
  />
  <Text>{sum(5, 10)}</Text>
  <Calendar
    onDayPress={day => {
      console.log('selected day', day);
    }}
  />
</SafeAreaView>
);
}

export default App;

App.test.tsx:
import App from './App';
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react-native';

describe('App', () => {
it('should render sum of two numbers', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<App />);
  expect(getByText('15')).toBeTruthy(); // 5 + 10 = 15
});
});

package.json:
"dependencies": {
"@testing-library/react-native": "^12.4.5",
"@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.73.6",
"react-native-calendars": "^1.1304.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.24.4",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.4",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.24.1",
"@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
"@react-native/babel-preset": "0.73.21",
"@react-native/eslint-config": "0.73.2",
"@react-native/metro-config": "0.73.5",
"@react-native/typescript-config": "0.73.1",
"@types/react": "^18.2.6",
"@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
"babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
"babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
"babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.1.4",
"eslint": "^8.19.0",
"jest": "^29.7.0",
"prettier": "2.8.8",
"react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
"typescript": "5.0.4"
},

jest.config.js:
module.exports = {
   preset: 'react-native',
   transform: {
       '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
   },
};

babel.config.js:
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        '@babel/preset-react',
        '@babel/preset-flow',
        'module:@react-native/babel-preset'
    ],
    plugins: [
        ['babel-plugin-styled-components', { "loose": true }],
        ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { "loose": true }]
    ]
 }

This file I have created on root folder of project, as per ChatGPT suggestion.
.babelrc:
{
   "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}

Error I am facing is as below:
 FAIL  ./App.test.tsx
 ● Test suite failed to run

Jest encountered an unexpected token

Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

Here's what you can do:
 • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
 • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
For information about custom transformations, see:
https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

Details:

/Users/viral/Desktop/testdemoproject/node_modules/react-native-calendars/src/index.ts:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export {default as Calendar} from './calendar';
                                                                                  ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

   7 |
   8 | import React from 'react';
>  9 | import { Calendar } from 'react-native-calendars';
     | ^
  10 | import {
  11 |   SafeAreaView,
  12 |   StatusBar,

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1505:14)
  at Object.require (App.tsx:9:1)
  at Object.require (App.test.tsx:1:1)


You have to mock the react-native-calendars.
